# PostgreSQL Function Error: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts

Tags: postgresql, function, gis, shapefile, pgrouting

I am currently new to PostgreSQL and I am implementing pgrouting using Esri Shapefiles.
The query I am writing is :

SELECT pgr_createTopology('point_file'::text,0.000001,'the_geom'::text, 'gid'::text);

"point_file" is the table name ,"the_geom" is the geometry column, and "gid" is the id column.

The error I am getting is :

ERROR:  function pgr_createtopology(text, numeric,text, text) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT pgr_createTopology('point_file'::text,0.000001,'th...

HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 8

NOTE: I have already added postgis as an extension.
I am using PostgreSQL 13 AND PostGIS 3.1.

Comment: Have you tried passing in more parameters? The documentation for it says it takes up to 8 parameters. 
https://docs.pgrouting.org/2.2/en/src/topology/doc/pgr_createTopology.html

Comment: Also, perhaps try to cast 0.000001 as a float8.